# Python - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Tags: python

I made a script to move excel file from source directory to specific directory. The script is work but I receive an error in the VSCode terminal that says:

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
File "C:\Users\aizat\OneDrive - PKT LOGISTICS (M) SDN BHD\Desktop\Python Test\Jabil-Inbound.py", line 195, in <module>
        shutil.move(source_dir+file_name,target_dir)
```

Attached links is my coding in python
https://pastebin.com/RSkHLSuU

Comment: make shure its not open in excel

Comment: there is no running excel process @BendikKnapstad

Comment: sorry i did not read the question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing writer.save() to writer.close() on line 140

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).